# asp.net Button Click event in Custom control

Tags: asp.net

i have a custom control which made by CodeBehind only (Class Library)

the control will create a asp button with a click event

i create the button in RenderControl method

and then set the event handler

```
Button m_oBTN = new Button();
m_oBTN.Text = "Submit";
m_oBTN.ID = "btnSubmit";
m_oBTN.CssClass = "btnSubmit";
m_oBTN.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnSubmit_Click);
```

however, it can success render the button, but no event has trigger when button click

do i need to use method like rasieEvent.....(i forgot name)?

how can i trigger the event when button is click?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably because you are not setting the event handler correctly! This line should be:

```
m_oBTN.Click += new System.EventHandler(m_oBTN);
```

Comment: are u sure, im making a custom control which contains some input field and a submit button, and ur code will cause Error 'm_oBTN' is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method'

Comment: yeah you are right, instead of System.EventHandler(m_oBTN); it should be System.EventHandler(event/method Name); Btw when you click on this button nothing happens?

Comment: yes, even i view generated source code, it do not contains any postback javascript